# Qt statically linked application error: linuxfb plugin not found by the application

Tags: libraries, qt, beagleboneblack, plugin, static-linking

I have successfully developed a graphical Qt 5.15.2 application using Qt Creator with dynamically linked libraries. For various reasons I have determined static linking would be better for my application.
I attempted to switch my development environment to use static libraries instead of dynamic. My application built with no errors, but when I deployed my application to a development board (a BeagleBone Black running Debian 11.5), I got the following error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "linuxfb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I passed in a `-platform linuxfb` command line argument, I built my own static Qt libraries, I added `CONFIG += static` to my `.pro` file, and I am using the static libraries in Qt Creator. Is there something special I need to do to get the `linuxfb` library/plugin to link? Any insight into how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt documentation is rather sparse, but it turns out my `.pro` file needed the line `QTPLUGIN += qlinuxfb`. This resolved the error I was getting.